# I have written a code for previewing a PDF file in Xamarin IOS. Now how can i annotate this PDF in Xamarin IOS using this QuickLook framework?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, quicklook

```
UIViewController currentController = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;
while (currentController.PresentedViewController != null)
    currentController = currentController.PresentedViewController;
UIView currentView = currentController.View;
QLPreviewController preview = new QLPreviewController();
QLPreviewItem item = new QLPreviewItemBundle(fileData.FileName, fileData.FilePath);
preview.DataSource = new PreviewControllerDS(item);

currentController.PresentViewController(preview, true, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

To begin, create a class that inherits from `QLPreviewControllerDataSource`.

```
public class QuickLookSource : QLPreviewControllerDataSource
{
    List documents;

    public QuickLookSource(List docs)
    {
        documents = docs;
    }

    public override nint PreviewItemCount(QLPreviewController controller)
    {
        return documents.Count;
    }

    public override IQLPreviewItem GetPreviewItem(QLPreviewController controller, nint index)
    {
        return new PreviewItem(documents[(int)index]);
    }
}

public class PreviewItem : QLPreviewItem
{
    NSUrl fileUrl;

    public override NSUrl ItemUrl => fileUrl;
    public override string ItemTitle => fileUrl.LastPathComponent;

    public PreviewItem(string url)
    {
        fileUrl = NSUrl.FromFilename(url);
    }
}
```

Then to present a preview, create a new `QLPreviewController` and set `DataSource` to you data source class. Since the controller can preview multiple files, make sure to set `CurrentPreviewItemIndex` before navigating to the controller:

```
var previewController = new QLPreviewController();
previewController.DataSource = new QuickLookSource(source.Documents);

previewController.CurrentPreviewItemIndex = indexPath.Row;
NavigationController.PushViewController(previewController, true);

// You can present modally instead
// PresentViewController(previewController, true, null);
```

Comment: I have created this class which is inheriting "QLPreviewControllerDataSource". And the preview functionality is working perfectly fine. Now i want to edit that previewed pdf and add annotations, for that we need to create a new class which inherits "QLPreviewControllerDelegate", after that i am stuck now, what next to do i order to annote the pdf.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh Sorry, I think `QLPreviewController` can not edit pdf file and add annotaions.

Comment: During WWDC 2019, the framework got a nice upgrade with the introduction of editing mode. QLPreviewItemEditingMode is the new addition to the framework that allows us to annotate images and PDFs and trim or convert videos easily.
For Reference: https://medium.com/better-programming/edit-pdfs-images-and-videos-using-quick-look-in-ios-13-ad2131080587

Comment: @AbhishekSingh Oh, that's cool! I will check that.

Comment: If you could help me implementing this for Xamarin IOS, it will be a great help.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh From shared link, do you set `preview.SetEditing(true, true);`? It should make the `previewController` be edited.

Comment: Yes i have added preview.SetEditing(true, true) before PresentViewController(previewController, true, null);

Then I have created an EditingDocuments Class which inherits QLPreviewControllerDelegate. This class overrides below 3 methods:-
1.GetEditingMode
2. DidSaveEditedCopy
3. DidUpdateContents

Now how can i use this class for editing pdf now?

Comment: @AbhishekSingh Okey, could you share a sample project link here? I will have a try in local site to find the solution.

Comment: Yeah its done, I am able to edit the pdf's now.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh Okey, you could update your solution in answer. Then it will be helpful for others who have the same problem.

Comment: Yes sure, i will. :)